# Odoo add tree and some fields

Tags: python, odoo-10

Anyone, I want to add tree and some fields inside of page.

For example, I write code like this :

```
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_hr_payslip_inherit_form_extended">
<field name="name">hr.payslip.inherit.form</field>
<field name="model">hr.payslip</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="hr_payroll.view_hr_payslip_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml"> 
    <xpath expr="//page[1]" position="after">
        <page string="Pendapatan Karyawan">
            <tree string="Tunjangan Gaji">
                <field name="gaji_pokok"/>
            </tree>
        </page>
    </xpath>  
</field>
</record>
```

Then, I have error message like this :

`Model 'hr.payslip' does not exist in registry`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Check whether have you installed 'hr' module in your system or not also check in your custom module 'hr' is in depends.

Comment: Yah, alright. It works. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I guess you haven't installed the HR module or check your manifest whether you have given HR module in depends.